# Why does resharper think a private readonly variable can be null?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, resharper

In the following code, Resharper 8 tells me that _myClasses has a "Possible 'System.NullReferenceException'".  Is this a bug in Resharper or is there something I am missing about how this code will work?  My understanding is that the readonly modifier makes it so I can only set _myClasses once and the one thing I am setting it to is an instance of something.  What scenario could this be null?

```
private readonly IList<MyClass> _myClasses = new List<MyClass>();

void Foo()
{
    _myClasses.Clear(); // Possible 'System.NullReferenceException'
}
```

Comment: in case of initialized to null at the first time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[readonly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acdd6hb7.aspx) means "can't change **after** constructor is completed". So any constructor can change its value to null (now or future written constructor).

> ...assignments to the fields introduced by the declaration can only occur as part of the declaration or in a constructor in the same class.

Sample:

```
class Foo
{
  private readonly string myClasses = "test";

  public Foo(int value) {  }    
  public Foo(string text) {  myClasses = text;}    
  public Foo() 
  {
     myClasses = null;
     Bar();
  }

  void Bar()
  {
    if (myClasses == null)
    {
     Console.WriteLine("Null???");
    }
  }
}
```

In sample above `Foo()` constructor will set `myClasses` to `null` and case exception if one relies on this value not be null.

Comment: The key thing I was missing was that I didn't realize readonly could be set multiple times.  I thought it could only be set at/before constructor and could only be set once during that time.

Comment: The problem is that even if you don't have the `Foo()` constructor (i.e. no way to set the member to `null`), Resharper will still tell you that the member might be `null`.